# Scale the iPad resolution images to fit android resolutions

Tags: resolution, image-resizing

Client just provided us with the iPad source code which contain all the images with 1024X768 resolution now I want to convert them to the android drawables i.e

1. 480*854
2. 320*480
3. 1280*800

I know I have to use 1.5 as scaling factor to convert hdpi to xhdpi and mdpi to hdpi.
but with this iPad resolution what resizing factor shall I use?

just the scaling factor to xhdpi would be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself in order to convert iPad images to android resolutions here is the scaling factors

**For Hdpi**

width  Scaling factor--------------0.625

Hieght Scaling factor---------------0.833

**For xhdpi**

Hieght Scaling factor--------------1.25

Width Scaling factor---------------1.04

**For mdpi**

Hieght Scaling factor--------------0.468

Width Scaling factor---------------0.416

Comment: It makes no sense to have different scaling factors for width and height.